# No suggestions from code completion in CounterClockwise

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I am using Eclipse Helios SR2 with CCW 0.5.0.STABLE002, and am unable to get code completion or namespace browsing working.

I have checked that the correct components as installed, as per the CCW installation instructions.

When I create a new Clojure project, then Clojure file I try and write a simple function and the editor is unable to find any suggestions for "printl". The project has clojure JAR files added, and these are in the project's build path.

I have never had this working with the current or previous versions of Eclipse (I can't tell you which ones they were as they have since been uninstalled).

I would welcome suggestions on what might be wrong.

Comment: Do you see any error in Error Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repl needs to be running, since the suggestions are based on the runtime environment.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This has been bugging me for a while.